# How to add bibliography to an AAAI conference

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'd like to submit a paper to a conference that requires AAAI format. I downloaded the template from [here](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/AuthorKit18.zip):
I then unzip the LaTeX folder. Under the same folder, I create a file named `ref.bib`, and add the following commands to formatting-instructions-latex-2018.tex right before `\end{document}`:

```
\bibliography{ref}

\bibliographystyle{aaai}
```

The `ref.bib` file only contains one reference for test purposes:

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
    AUTHOR="John Doe",
    TITLE="The Book without Title",
    PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
    YEAR="2100",
}
```

I tried to compile the formatting-instructions-latex-2018.tex, and every time I got the error message:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}
```

I checked the formatting-instructions-latex-2018.bbl and found there are only two lines as follows:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\end{thebibliography}
```

However, when I create a simple test.tex still under the same folder with the following commands: (based on a tutorial [here](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/bibtex/): and I changed bibliography style to AAAI)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aaai18}

\begin{document}

Random citation \cite{DUMMY:1} embedded in text.

\newpage

\bibliography{ref} 
\bibliographystyle{aaai}

\end{document}
```

Compiling test.tex is successful. I checked `test.bbl` and the following lines are there:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{DUMMY:1}
J.~Doe, {\em The Book without Title}.
\newblock Dummy Publisher, 2100.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I even tried to copy the above code to formatting-instructions-latex-2018.bbl and it still didn't work.

I really don't understand why this error can happen, while the test.tex in the same directory does not have any issue. I believe it's supposed to be simple stuff and I'm very frustrated that it kept failing.

Any advice is much appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that

> I tried to compile the formatting-instructions-latex-2018.tex, and every time I got the error message:
>       `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}`

and the result was

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\end{thebibliography}
```

If you think about it, makes sense. The `bibliography` environment is just an `itemize` in disguise, and you can't have an `itemize` without items (try it, make a document with an empty `itemize` environment).

However, when you compiled your `test.tex`, there was not problems, and the `bibliography` environment had something in it. And this something was there because of the `\cite{DUMMY:1}` that you inserted, that did not exist in the previous document.

So to make the original document work, either:

1. Remove the `\bibliography{ref}` or don't compile bibTeX, or;
2. Add a `\cite{DUMMY:1}` anywhere in the document.

Furthermore, you said that

> I even tried to copy above code to formatting-instructions-latex-2018.bbl and it still didn't work.

The `.bbl` file is automatically generated by bibTeX, so when you compiled the document, the one you put there was replaced by the correct, empty one.